# Firestore where 'array-contains' query doesn't work with references

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I have a collection 'chats' with a members array which contains users participating in the chat. The problem is I want to get all chats where the current user is participating.

I do this with this query:

```
getUserChats(): Observable<Chat[]> {
    return this.auth.currUser
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(user => this.afs
            .collection('chats', ref => ref.where('members', 'array-contains', `/users/${user.uid}`))
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(actions => {
                return actions.map(action => {
                  const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
                  const id = action.payload.doc.id;
                  return {id, ...data};
                });
              })
            ) as Observable<Chat[]>
        )
      );
  }
```

This works well for strings, but doesn't work with References. How can I also make it work on References?

[image: Image with Collections]

The green works the red one doesn't work

Green: String
Red: Reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Alex Mamo answer is right, you need a DocumentReference.

**NOTE: YOU CAN'T CREATE ONE YOURSELF!**

You have to get the reference by querying firebase!

**Code:**

```
return this.auth.currUser
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap(user => this.afs
            .collection('chats', ref => ref.where('members', 'array-contains', this.afs
              .collection('users')
              .doc<User>(user.uid)
              .ref))
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(actions => {
                return actions.map(action => {
                  const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
                  const id = action.payload.doc.id;
                  return {id, ...data};
                });
              })
            ) as Observable<Chat[]>
        )
      );
```

The crucial part is the 'value' part which is:

```
this.afs
              .collection('users')
              .doc<User>(user.uid)
              .ref
```

You query and **THEN** get the reference with .ref!

That's it! That's how you query for a DocumentReference!

Answer (score 5):

It works with strings because you're passing as the third argument to the `where()` function the following argument:

```
/users/${user.uid}
```

Which is of type String. If you want to work with references as well, instead of a String, pass an actual [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) object.

Comment: Do you know the Class Name? Can't find anything

Comment: Yes, [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

Comment: And if I import it from angular/fire/firestore it's an interface

Comment: I don't understand, you cannot import the DocumentReference or you cannot pass the object?

Comment: I can't import the DocumentReference Object you sent.


And there is another DocumentReference from @angular/fire/firestore which is an Interface

Comment: Hi Filip! Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: No, still can't import the class (From your links to the docs) itself only the interface from @angular/fire/firestore. So I can't create a document reference object