# Angular7 Firestore import DocumentReference Class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get the DocumentReference class and how to use it with an Path String? Any ideas?

I've tried:

```
import DocumentReference = firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
```

but it didn't solve my problem.

I need this for querying an array of References to User's uid to check if they are in this array.

```
.collection('chats', ref => ref.where('members', 'array-contains', new DocumentReference(`/users/${user.uid}`)))
```

Error Messages:

```
ERROR in src/app/core/firebase/chat.service.ts(11,28): error TS2686: 'firebase' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
src/app/core/firebase/chat.service.ts(47,80): error TS2673: Constructor of class 'DocumentReference' is private and only accessible within the class declaration.
```

**Update #1:**

Changed the import to:

```
import {firestore} from 'firebase';
import DocumentReference = firestore.DocumentReference;
```

Now the error changed to:

```
ERROR in src/app/core/firebase/chat.service.ts(47,80): error TS2673: Constructor of class 'DocumentReference' is private and only accessible within the class declaration.
```

Answer: [Firestore where 'array-contains' query doesn't work with references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205155/firestore-where-array-contains-query-doesnt-work-with-references)

Comment: more information about your computing environment, what you are trying to do, or what error messages you are getting would help people who might know how to help you

Comment: Sorry. Edited the post! @stackuser83

Comment: `var docRef = new firestore.DocumentReference('/users/${user.uid}')`? you also might want to change `user.uid` to `user_uid` or something without a period, for when maybe you have to reference it later, not sure if using a period there would complicate things.

Comment: then u might want `docRef.collection('chats', ref => ref.where('members', 'array-contains', xxx-not sure what you wan't here but maybe not what you have-xxx`)))`

Comment: Good idea but the function takes only 1 Parameter @ewizard

Comment: and u still need `import {firestore} from 'firebase';`

Comment: hmm the string is 1 parameter....you sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: oh wait...one second i see what is going on

Comment: have u initialized the database in the code?

Comment: I need 2 inputs: which collection and the ref function @ewizard

Comment: Everything other call and code works except this piece of code which works with normal strings but not with references.

Comment: u need 2 "inputs" ("parameters"?) for the DocumentReference constructor?

Comment: `new DocumentReference('chats', ref => ref.where('members', 'array-contains', xxx-not sure what you wan't here but maybe not what you have-xxx))`

Comment: i havent used firebase/firestore with angular yet, but i know angular and firebase/firestore, but it just seems like maybe you are going about this differently than you should, i can't really find any documentation that looks like the code you have, where are you getting it from?

Comment: also `ref.where` works like this `ref.where('key', '== (or similar operator)', 'value')`

Comment: 1. The DocumentReference Object doesn't expect any parameters. 
2. I need 2 Inputs for the querry (1st: TheCollection, 2nd: the query as function)
3. It should work like this because it works with strings. Source for example YT Channel: AngularFirebase
4. the operator 'array-contains' is a valid operator for checking for values in arrays. 
5. The 'value' part is the tricky part since you have to pass an DocumentReference to a user instead of just the string, which would be the easiest way possible and could be done right now but just doesn't seem right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205155/firestore-where-array-contains-query-doesnt-work-with-references Gives the answer!